# Execution efficiency difference: one SQL VS. two split SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL, and the context as below:

```
mysql> show create table letter_index\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: letter_index
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `letter_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `target` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `target_idx` (`target`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 


mysql> show create table letter_data\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: letter_data
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `letter_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Table `letter_index` defined the letter relation: who write it and to whom to receive, while table `letter_data` stored the letter content message.

The table `letter_index` column `data_id` is referenced to the table `letter_data` primary key `id`.

---

I want to get someone's all received messages. When I use one nesting SQL to get the result, it usually costs much more time than two split SQLs. Demo as below:

One SQL:

```
mysql> select * from letter_data where id in (select data_id from letter_index where target=10718)
  ...
  ...  # query result
  ...
78 rows in set (52.01 sec)
```

Split:

```
mysql> select data_id from letter_index where target=10718;
  ...
  ...  # query result
  ...
78 rows in set (0.25 sec)


mysql> select * from letter_data where id in (1,2,..`data_id result`..);
  ...
  ...  # query result
  ...
78 rows in set (2.04 sec)
```

The efficiency difference is huge!

Explained the relative SQLs and there's some hints:

```
mysql> explain select * from letter_data where id in (select data_id from letter_index where target=10718);
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | letter_data  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  | 1103585 | Using where | 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | letter_index | ref  | target_idx    | target_idx | 4       | const |      78 | Using where | 
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+


mysql> explain select data_id from letter_index where target=10718;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | letter_index | ref  | target_idx    | target_idx | 4       | const |   78 |       | 
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+


mysql> explain select * from letter_data where id in (1,2,..`data_id result`..);
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | letter_data | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   78 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

My question is, why the nesting SQL table `letter_data` possible_keys are `NULL` while the individual one are `PRIMARY`?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why the sql-server tag?

Comment: @jarlh sorry for that

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple `INNER JOIN`? Subquery is completely pointless, especially with `IN` operator.

Comment: Thx @Mjh , while is there any scenario where we prefer `in` to `inner join` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I miss something, but why you don't use `INNER JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT
    ld.*
FROM
    letter_data ld
INNER JOIN letter_index li ON li.data_id = ld.id
WHERE li.target = 10718
```

Result will be the same, the big difference is that MySQL will not materialize any subquery.

Comment: I see, is there any scenario where we prefer `in` to `inner join` ?

Comment: Usually `IN` is used when you have a list of values coming from outside (server-side script, static list etc.). When you want to filter data by such list from other table, is better to use `INNER JOIN` or `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS`. When using an IN with a subquery, the database process the entire subquery first, then the overall query as a whole, matching up based on the relationship specified for the IN. With EXISTS or JOIN, the database will return true/false while checking the relationship specified. Unless the table in the subquery is very small, EXISTS or JOIN will perform much better than IN.

Answer (score 1):

The data types are different in the tables, which leads to a type conversion, which prevents MySQL to use indexes in the first query.
(`letter_index.data_id` is unsigned, while `letter_data.id` is signed.) This is why MySQL is using full table scan on the letter_data table.

Use the same data type, create an index on the data_id column, create a foreign key.

To improve the performance of the query, you can use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.

To explain your second way: both queries are simple range or constant searches, no difficulties especially when you have an index on the filtered fields.